# Parsing a single XML section using a query string with PHP

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml

I'm trying to retrieve a single section from an XML file using PHP.
Here's the code I'm using:

```
<?php
$articles = simplexml_load_file('articles.xml');

foreach ($articles as $articlecontent)
{
    $title   = $articlecontent->title;
    $content = $articlecontent->content;
    $author  = $articlecontent->author;
    $date    = $articlecontent['date'];

    echo "<h1>",$title,"</h1>\n",
         "<p><i>",$date,"</i></p>\n",
         "<p>",$content,"</p>\n",
         "<p>",$author,"</p>\n",
         "<p><time>",$date,"</time></p>\n"
    ;
}
?>
```

Which shows all the sections in the XML file, but how can I parse just one result but do so using a query string?

Example: `articles.php?title=section-one` will retrieve the XML section with the title "section-one"

Answer (score 0):

You get the title from the query string by getting it from PHP's superglobal `$_GET` array, like this:

```
$title = false;
if (isset($_GET['title']))
{
    $title = $_GET['title'];
}
```

and then the simplest way would be to compare it to the title from the XML file in your `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Way to get title from url is using $_GET array, then to get required article by title i think you could use xpath which won't require foreach loop

```
$title = $_GET['title']; 
// there should go some sanitizing
$articles = simplexml_load_file('articles.xml');

//search for article by title
//assuming that xml root tag is articles and article tag is article and searching by attribute named title
$foundArticles = $articles->xpath('articles/article[@title='.$title.']'); 
//query depends on xml structure 
// now you have array of matched articles with matching title from url
foreach($foundArticles as $singleArticle)
{
    //do printing here
}
```

This code is not tested, but principle should work.

Comment: How would the content from the selected 'title' be parsed?

Comment: if you only need single article parsed you can check for not empty array and then $foundArticles[0] will be your article then you can access every attribute as array $foundArticles[0]['some_attr'] and you can get all children with $foundArticles[0]->children()

Answer (score 0):

To receive Query String Variable (in our case 'title') from URL you can use `$_REQUEST` also. Little bit corrected code (@user1597483) with some more advanced updates.

```
$articles = simplexml_load_file('articles.xml');
$title = "";
if(isset($_REQUEST['title'])) //receiving Query String from URL
    $title = $_REQUEST['title'];
if(count($articles)):
    //Fixed search  means that will one return article if 'section-one' in title
    //$result = $articles->xpath("//article[title='Section-one']");

    //Match All Search means that will return all articles that contains 'section-one' in title
    $result = $articles->xpath("//article[contains(translate(title, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),'".strtolower($title)."')]");
    foreach ($result as $articleItem):
        $title=$articleItem->title;
        $content=$articleItem->content;
        $author=$articleItem->author;
        $date=$articleItem->date;
        echo "<h1>",$title,"</h1>\n";
        echo "<p><i>",$date,"</i></p>\n";
        echo "<p>",$content,"</p>\n";
        echo "<p>",$author,"</p>\n";
        echo "<p><time>",$date,"</time></p>\n";
    endforeach;
endif;
```

In the code above I have specified two types of filter through which you can get result with Specific Article by exact match or wild card type matching by `contains` function. And I have also used `translate` function which will convert value of `title` element to lowercase and also converted value of Query String Variable to lowercase. So that regardless of Upper/Lower case, condition will be checking with lowercase and if condition matched then resultant articles will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by inserting a condition into the `foreach` loop testing if the title-filter is in action and does not match. If so, skip that entry by using the `continue` keyword:

```
$titleFilter = trim(isset($_GET['title']) ? $_GET['title'] : '');

...

foreach ($articles as $articlecontent)
{
    $title   = $articlecontent->title;

    if (strlen($titleFilter) and $title !== $titleFilter) {
        continue;
    }

    ...
```